# Use of librte_lpm library in multiple processes

Tags: dpdk

I would like to use multi-process, process-1 will only update LPM table. Process-2 will process pktmbuf with LPM lookup

Details are subject to following conditions

- Process-1, is part of application in way is non-dpdk based which only has librte_lpm and bare minimum linked to make it work.

  - Process-2, is part of application which is full fledged dpdk based which has all the dpdk libraries linked to it.

Also note always updates in process-1 to lpm happens less frequently.

Thanks,
Regards,
Venu

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? is your question `I would like to use multi-process, process-1 will only update LPM table. Process-2 will process pktmbuf with LPM lookup?`

Answer (score 0):

If both the process invokes rte_eal_init as primary/secondary model it will work. Process-1 (primary) need not invoke any other API apart from rte_lpm for add/delete. While Process-2 can invoke rte_eth_rx_burst and do rte_lpm_lookup.

Comment: Internally, rte_lpm does memory allocation what about that still the mempools / hugpages are required.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, if you intend to use DPDK ports, libraries, LPM your primary has to invoke rte_eal_init with port configuration and library setup. Then the primary can simply do a `while (1)` to keep master thread alive